# How to Barriers implementation at OS

Tags: java, operating-system, memory-barriers

How to Barriers implementation which multiple processes/threads wait a specific location in the code until other threads in the system have reached the same location?

Here is the link for enlarged information with example. Thanks for advice and comments.

[Document View](https://docsend.com/view/ww5ipvs)

Comment: From the document: *You are expected to use Semaphor and/or Mutex provided by the library that you have used.* If you're not sure how to proceed, I'd suggest reading up on semaphores and mutexes, because a strong understanding there should lead you to an answer to your question.

Comment: Barriers don't wait. That's one of the reasons why discussing memory barriers in the context of Java is pointless. You need *happens-before* relationships to build correct multi-threaded programs. The specification does not even mention “memory barriers”.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier or Java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch from java concurrency api.

For your problem Java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier looks more suitable but again depends on complete requirment.

Please find refrence links for both below:

[CyclicBarrier](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-util-concurrent-cyclicbarrier-java/)

[CountDownLatch](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/countdownlatch-in-java/)